# sms uri scheme support mobile browsers

Tags: html, mobile, browser, sms, uri

The following anchor tag utilises the SMS URI scheme to open the messenging app on supported mobile browsers:

```html
<a href="sms:+447787000000?body=hello">Send SMS</a>
```

Does anybody know what mobile browsers are supported, or where I can find a suppport list?

I am most interested to know the earliest versions of ios and chrome for android supporting this.

Comment: It seems there is about 34% browser support today. See https://caniuse.com/mdn-api_navigator_registerprotocolhandler_scheme_parameter_sms